# fastest way to display "unique object" on screen

Tags: windows, computer-vision, frame

So, I have written programs to simulate couple things like opening the browser, searching for a URL, zoom in , zoom out, etc.
I am video recording the whole activity with a really fast camera(120fps).

But the algorithm processes and gives an output from a particular start point in the video.
And I have made the "Disappearing of the CMD prompt from the screen" as the start point from which the algorithm has to actually process and ignores all the frames before the disappearing of the CMD prompt.

PS: I selected CMD prompt since it opens and closes the fastest in windows.

Now for windows it works fine. But I want to make it generic to all platforms.
Is there anyway I can have an "unique object" on screen and make it appear & disappear within 1-2 frames.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You could fairly easily write a program in a cross-platform GUI framework like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) that simply displays a specific image on the screen for a specified period of time and then closes. You could make it as complex as you'd like to make it easy to detect -- perhaps you just display a specific [QR code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) or something so you could use an existing library to check for its presence.